# How to indent more spaces on the table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

On the List of Tables: How to indent the letter c just a few more spaces, so that the c in Success is just under the C in Correlation.

[image]

```
  \documentclass[12pt,reqno]{siugrad51}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{7}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\medskip}
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\enspace \thecontentslabel.\enspace}
{}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}
    
    \addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-0.45in} {CHAPTER} ~\hfill \underline{PAGE}\par}
    
    \renewcommand\listfigurename{LIST OF FIGURES}
    \renewcommand\listtablename{LIST OF TABLES}
    
    \addtocontents{lot}{\vspace{-0.15in} \underline{TABLE} ~\hfill \underline{PAGE}\par}
    \addtocontents{lof}{\vspace{-0.15in} \underline{FIGURE} ~\hfill \underline{PAGE}\par}
    %\listoftables % comment out if no tables
    \renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1~}
    
    \tableofcontents
    {%
        \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
        \renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}%
        \listoftables%
    }
    
    {%
        \let\oldnumberline\numberline%
        \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%
        \listoffigures%
    }

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
%\raggedright
\parindent=.35in


%\input{introduction}

\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \begin{center}
        \caption{Correlation Coefficients of the Compared Frameworks in Terms of the Success Rate } % title of Table
        \label{table:correlation1} % is used to refer this table in the text
        {\footnotesize
            
        }  
        
        
    \end{center}
\end{table}






\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only did some minor changes to your setup. (marked with `<<<<<<<<`) to get the alignment requested. I suggest you don't put the word "Table" before each table number, since you already have the title "TABLE" above.
[image: enteadption here]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex
 
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{siugrad51}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{7}

\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\medskip}
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\enspace \thecontentslabel.\enspace}
{}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\begin{document}
    
    \addtocontents{toc}{\hspace{-2.5em}{CHAPTER} ~\hfill \underline{PAGE}\par} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    
    \renewcommand\listfigurename{LIST OF FIGURES}
    \renewcommand\listtablename{LIST OF TABLES}

    \addtocontents{lot}{\hspace{-2.5em}\underline{TABLE} ~\hfill \underline{PAGE}\par}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \addtocontents{lof}{\hspace{-2.5em}\underline{FIGURE} ~\hfill \underline{PAGE}\par}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    %\listoftables % comment out if no tables
    
    \tableofcontents
    {%
%       \let\oldnumberline\numberline% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%       \renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \listoftables%
    }
    
    {%
%       \let\oldnumberline\numberline% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
%       \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \listoffigures%
    }
    
    \newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    %\raggedright
    \parindent=.35in
    
    %\input{introduction}
    
    \chapter{Introduction}
    
    \begin{table}[htb]
        \begin{center}
            \caption{Correlation Coefficients of the Compared Frameworks in Terms of the Success Rate } % title of Table
            \label{table:correlation1} % is used to refer this table in the text
            {\footnotesize              
            }           
        \end{center}
    \end{table} 
\end{document}
```

If you want to go back to your setup replace the `\vspace{...}` for `\hspace{...}` in the preamble.

Comment: many thanks, it works